# cursor is not at end of text after routine adds 1 char

Tags: vb.net

I type a couple of letters in the textbox in vb.net and then hit the up arrow. This adds an accented e to the textbox but the cursor is not at end of text.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        MessageBox.Show("Up arrow key")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "é"
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length + 1

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a very strange behaviour but it seems than vb.net is not updating the positions until TextBox1_KeyDown has finished.

What I propose until anyone propose something better is starting a timer and doing the updating of the SelectionStart in the Timer.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            MessageBox.Show("Up arrow key")
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "é"
            Timer1.Start()
        End If

    End Sub

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Stop()
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
    End Sub
```

And by the way, you do not need the +1 in TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length + 1

Comment: Or possibly use KeyUp event?

Comment: Many thanks Oscar it works like magic. I was beginning to think I was really dumb.